# How to vertically align lists to pandas dataframe in python

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, zip

I have a dataset as follows.

```
scores = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
years = [2001, 2002, 2003]
columns = ['Years', 'Scores']
```

I want to convert these three lists to a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
   Years Scores
0  2001   0.1
1  2002   0.2
2  2003   0.3
```

I am using the following code.

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data=[scores],index=[years],columns=columns)
print(dataset)
```

However, this gives me the error.

```
AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns
```

I think it algns the data horizontally.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list` with `zip`:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(years, scores)),columns=columns)
print(dataset)
   Years  Scores
0   2001     0.1
1   2002     0.2
2   2003     0.3
```

Comment: After spending almost an hour... huge relief

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.column_stack`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

scores = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
years = [2001, 2002, 2003]
columns = ['Years', 'Scores']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([years, scores]), index=[years], columns=columns)

      Years  Scores
2001  2001.0     0.1
2002  2002.0     0.2
2003  2003.0     0.3
```

To get rid of float values in `Years` column:

```
df['Years'] = df['Years'].astype(int)

      Years  Scores
2001   2001     0.1
2002   2002     0.2
2003   2003     0.3
```

Comment: yes, but numpy here is not good idea, because convert all values to floats :(

Comment: Ah yes i just noticed! Let me see if there is an easy workaround